# I'm having trouble in WordPress update failed could not create directory

Tags: wordpress

I am stuck with a problem, and it has been more than 12 hours that I have been searching for solutions, and I have not reached any results. I hope that someone will help me.

I transferred sites from one server to another server from the Transfer Tool available in whm, and after the transfer was completed, I was surprised that most of the sites had not transferred their databases. After searching, I learned that the problem occurred due to the difference in the version of databases between the two servers.

I started manually transferring the databases to each site separately, and the problem that I started facing after uploading the database is that the site does not accept updating themes or plugins and needs an FTP connection. After researching to solve this problem, I found one of the solutions that suggests adding code in the wp-config file.

```
   define('FS_METHOD', 'direct' );
```

After adding this code, I was able to get rid of the problem, but unfortunately I encountered another problem, and I did not find a solution to it, which is when updating any theme or plugin, an error message appears that says

```
   Update failed: Could not create directory. /home/shuhoudc/public_html/wp-content/upgrade/woocommerce-7.2.0-en
```

I need help resolving this problem and please cooperate and help, thank you

[An illustration of the problem that occurs when updating one of the plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxTye.png)

These are some pictures that show the permissions of files and folders

1. [Illustrative image permissions for files and folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmaFu.png)
2. [Illustrative image permissions for files and folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJONE.png)
3. [Illustrative image permissions for files and folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJk5W.png)
4. [Illustrative image permissions for files and folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PGgY.png)
5. [Illustrative image permissions for files and folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYOT4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this-

sudo chmod 777 -R /home/shuhoudc/public_html